# Changing Active Model Serializers Default Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

If I want to switch from the default attributes adapter to the JSON API adapter, where would I do this?

The getting started states this:

**Generally speaking, you as a user of AMS will write (or generate) these serializer classes. If you want to use a different adapter, such as a JSON API, you can change this in an initializer:**

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

What initializer are they referring to? Do I create a new one? Sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, initializers are put under the `app/config/initializers` directory in a Rails app.

So, in your case, you can create a new file there: `ams.rb` and put those content in that file:

```
# app/config/initializers/ams.rb    
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

Also, see this [github issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/803).

If you want to be using the `:json_api` format, you have to use the `0.10.0` branch off of Github.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So I tried that earlier and I get an undefined method `config' for ActiveModel::Serializer:Class...am I missing a step from just creating the initializers file?

Comment: which version of AMS are you using?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/803
`If you want to be using the :json_api format, you have to use the 0.10.0 branch off of Github`

Comment: uninitialized constant ActiveModelSerializers (NameError), I have put `require 'active_model_serializers'
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
` in config/initializers/ams.rb, throwing above error when restarting rails server

Answer (score 5):

For newer version of AMS put this to `config/initializers/ams.rb`:

```
require 'active_model_serializers'

ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

Comment: uninitialized constant ActiveModelSerializers (NameError), I have put require 'active_model_serializers' ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api in config/initializers/ams.rb, throwing above error when restarting rails server

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file with any name inside `app/config/initializers/`  and add:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

All the files under initalizers directory run during initialization irrespective of the file name.