# How do you get the serializer to output JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to use `active_model_serializers` to convert an object to JSON. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620859/changing-active-model-serializers-default-adapter), I created a file called `config/initializers/serializers.rb` with the following code:

```
puts 'Running serializers.rb.'
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

I see `Running serializers.rb.` when resetting the database, but not when running the Rails console. In the console, when I type `UserSerializer.new(User.first).as_json`, I get `{:id=>1, :name=>"Regular User", :created_at=>Thu, 07 Jul 2016 06:03:46 UTC +00:00, :lists=>[{:id=>1, :title=>"Before Wednesday"}]}`, which is clearly not JSON. How do I get the `as_json` method to actually return JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserSerializer.new(User.first).to_json

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json