# Rails render json returning data as first attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm retrieving all my items with a REST API call (get) and returning a json, this is the code in the controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

def index
  @people = Person.all

  render json: @people
end
end
```

It's returning, but with a "data" field at the beginning:

```
{"data":
   [
      {"id":"1","type":"people","attributes": {"name":"survivorTest","age":"55"}},
      {"id":"2","type":"people","attributes": {"name":"test666","age":"44"}},
      {"id":"3","type":"people","attributes": {"name":"test666","age":"6666"}}
   ]
}
```

This is my route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :people
end
```

How can I return only the attributes from each row?

Comment: Are you setting ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = "data" somewhere in your app?

Comment: I'm not, where should I set it?

Comment: Are you using [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)? That JSON looks exactly like the [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/) format. If you are using AMS, you should select another adapter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620859/changing-active-model-serializers-default-adapter

Comment: That was it, I'm using AMS, and I've made the initializer configuration that was overriding AMS I believe. It's working now, thanks!

Comment: Good, you can post an answer the question yourself to help others who have the same problem (and get some rep).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [.as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @people = Person.all

    render json: @people.as_json
  end
end
```

Also, your current code, `render json: @people`, if I remember correctly, would be calling [.to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) behind the scenes, which **by default** should *not* have `data` as the root of the hash... so I would go search for `.to_json` in your code to see if you are overriding it anywhere... or just use `.as_json`

Comment: Thanks! Both of them worked, but the strange part is that I have another application that works without them, I just can't see what is different

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm using AMS, and I've made the initializer configuration explained in this post:

[Changing Active Model Serializers Default Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620859/changing-active-model-serializers-default-adapter)

This configuration was overriding AMS, making the JSON render the original output, and not the serialized one.